# python calling similar variables

Tags: python, tkinter, self

I have a big problem using tkinter with `self` here is my code
Could people please give an answer, thanks! The error I get is something like,`self could not be given a variable outside a function`.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

class start():
    global self
    self = root

    def __init__():
        self.title('__init__')
        self.geometry('300x300')

    __init__(self) 

class window_extra():

    def canvas(self):
        global self
        selfc = Canvas(self, bg='black').pack()

    canvas(self)

self.mainloop()
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem? The error I get is related to the argument `self` and `global self` in `canvas`. You can rename the argument to anything you would like, but truthfully I have no idea what you are intending to do. Can you explain your objective?

Comment: What in the world are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Guydangerous99 `global self` is a *really* bad idea.  The `self` variable within a class is sacred and should not be overwritten!

Comment: I'm using self in the class, not __init__ and I use selfc in canvas, not self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use self as a variable name as it is used to specify if something is an attribute of the instance of the class.

You do not need to use global in classes either as class attributes are used in most cases when dealing with variables that are needed through the class.

Judging by the code you have shown I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
from tkinter import *

class start():

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.master = root
        self.master.title('__init__')
        self.master.geometry('300x300')
        Canvas(self.master, bg='black').pack()

root = Tk()
start(root)
root.mainloop()
```

However I believe you are struggling with the OOP method of programing and I would suggest to not use OOP to start with if this is the case.

Maybe take a few tutorials on youtube or hit up Codecadamy.

In response to your comments:

> In my Opinion using init properly is a bad idea. I use it as a regular def. I doesn't matter if I use self global, unless the function/class variable is called self.
>
> I respect the proper use of **init**, but I just find the whole thing with, **init** and self.master I just don't get any of it!

Lack of understanding a thing does not mean said thing is bad. The use of `self.master` is there to provide a class attribute that ties back to the root Tk() variable. This allows any method within the class to interact with the instance of Tk(). I can't speak to other programing languages but the use of `self` is a very important in OOP for python. It may not be 100% required to reserve `self` for referencing to either the instance of the object or the class attribute but it is the accepted and known use of `self` and really should not be changed/overwritten.

Comment: Only part I have trouble with is "You cannot use self as a variable name...". I don't think there is anything special about the name `self`, but perhaps that's exactly what the asker is missing - that it's just the first (implicit) argument and the name itself doesn't matter.

Comment: @ryachza fair enough. I have updated my answer to say `should not use` instead of `cannot`.

Comment: @ryachza: you are correct there is nothing special about `self`, except that almost every python programmer on the planet will assume it refers to an instance of an object. While you can use the name `self` any way you see fit, it's best not to pick a name that will confuse most programmers.

Comment: @BryanOakley Totally agree. My point was only that it seems the asker has some fundamental misunderstandings regarding the Python OOP flavor, so I see this as an educational opportunity and hate to see false information presented.

Comment: In my Opinion using __init__ properly is a bad idea. I use it as a regular `def`. I doesn't matter if I use `self` global, unless the function/class variable is called self.

Comment: @Guydangerous99 why do you think using `init` "properly" is a bad idea?

Comment: I respect the proper use of `__init__`, but I just find the whole thing with, `__init__ and self.master` I just don't get any of it!

Comment: @Guydangerous99 I have added some detail to my answer in regards to self and your comments.

Comment: Another thing that strikes me, is you don't actually call __init__, and can you use self.master outside the __init__ function.

Comment: @Guydangerous99  One does not need to call init as it is done automatically in a class. And yes self.master can be used outside of init because the self prefix makes it a class attribute.

Comment: Thanks, get it now, will tick answer! `__init_`!

Answer (score 0):

I restructured for some simplicity, but I think that you need a better understanding of objects in Python before going too much further down the GUI route.  I think that you mean something like this:

```
from tkinter import *

# creates a subclass of Tk() called 'Application'; class names by convention
# use CamelCase; best to stick with convention on this one

class Application(tkinter.Tk):

    # you don't have to create an explicit invocation of '__init__', it 
    # is automatically run when you instantiate your class (last line)

    def __init__():
        super().__init__()  # initialize the super class (the 'tkinter.Tk()')

        self.title('__init__')  # use 'self' to refer to this object - do not declare it as global!  it is only valid within the object!
        self.geometry('300x300')

        self.my_canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self, bg='black') # save an instance of your canvas for easy reference later
        self.my_canvas.pack()  # pack as a separate step (only required if you plan to use the canvas later... or ever)

        self.mainloop()  # begin the tkinter loop

# this 'if __name__ ...' is a good idea in most cases, allows you to import `Application` into other
# files without actually running it unless you want to from that other file

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application()  # start your class
```

Comment: You should point out that packing on a separate line is only needed if you are going to update the canvas object directly later.

Comment: @Mike-SMT edited, but difficult to imagine a scenario in which a canvas is created without wanting to use is later.

Comment: I agree however its more about the use of pack() and not the fact that its on a canvas. If you are going to say to use pack on a separate line then you should have some example as to why this is required in some situations. The OP clearly is new to Tkinter and this is information that will help them going forward.